# Can a terraform resource name have a dot in it?

Tags: terraform

Can I have a resource like

```
resource "foo" "bar.baz"{
  ...
}
```

or will the `.` mess me up later? In particular, will this be allowed:

```
resource "foo" "other"{
  ...
  depends_on = [ "foo.bar.baz" ]
}
```

I'm currently doing something like that but getting an invalid resource error and I'm unsure if its from that dot or not. I checked on [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/resource-addressing.html#resource_name) page, but its not clear from there if its valid to have a `.` in a resource name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should avoid using the `.` in resource identifiers, as `.` is used by Terraform to access attributes from resources.

> [Attributes of other resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#attributes-of-other-resources)
>
> The syntax is TYPE.NAME.ATTRIBUTE. For example, `${aws_instance.web.id}` will interpolate the ID attribute from the aws_instance resource named web. If the resource has a count attribute set, you can access individual attributes with a zero-based index, such as `${aws_instance.web.0.id}`. You can also use the splat syntax to get a list of all the attributes: `${aws_instance.web.*.id}`.